# Is there java libraries ".jar" for performing backup and Restore

Tags: java, backup, restore

Is there java libraries ".jar" for performing backup and Restore for both file and directories ? to be used from my java application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a bit vague, what exactly do you want the library to do?

Comment: backup file or directories from localhost to a remote server and restore them when i need. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **Java Backup** ([jBup](http://jbup.sourceforge.net)), which wants to be a professional solution, but was last updated in 2009. You could also have a look at [**JFileSync**](http://jfilesync.sourceforge.net/).

Additionally, please search for other queries similar to yours, e.g. [What Java file synchronization/backup library do you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348255/what-java-file-synchronization-backup-library-do-you-recommend).